# How can I watch an Infrared movie in normal color

Tags: video, video-playback

I run Win7 HP. I have a WMV video, shot in infrared mode. The video has some greenish-gray color. The video looks like as in the image below;

[image: Screenshot]

But I want to watch the video in normal color format. How can I do this? Is there any specific player / plugin for this? I am not looking for a video editing program might be able to swap colours. I **don't want to make any changes** to the master file, or to re encode it. I just want to watch it in normal colors.

Thanks in advance...`:)`

Comment: Nothing can restore colour that's not already there. A video editing program might be able to swap colours and provide a reasonable approximation of a daytime scene, but I don't know of anything that can do it in real time.

Answer (score 0):

If the video was recorded in normal with a infrared filter being applied after processing, then in theory you could split the 2, but if it was recorded with a infrared device, then you have just, infrared.